# python site packages directory

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python

I have for some reason two locations for python site packages.

Python itself is here:

```
> $ which python
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

My Path Variable is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/opengeo/pgsql/9.1/bin
```

xlrd is installed here and can be accessed from python

```
> $ pip install xlrd
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): xlrd in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlrd
>>>
```

numpy is installed here and can not be accessed from python

```
> $ pip install numpy
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

What do I have to do to get numpy also working with python. I am looking for the 'cleanest solution'.

Comment: Don't you have a Python in `/usr/bin/` ? and Did you change your `$path` variable ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler: would it makes sense to delete the $path variable?

Comment: WHat does `which pip` give?

Comment: @Mark `$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Do Not deleting $path (that would be an awful idea). what does `echo $PATH` give ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - it's in her question...

Comment: How did you happen to not have `/usr/bin/python`? Did you remove it?

Comment: @MattDMo It wasn't when I asked.

Answer (score 1):

As a short-term solution, you should be able to run

```bsh
cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

as the versions of python are the same, and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is (amongst other places) where your python binary will be looking for modules.

I'm concerned that `/usr/bin/python` doesn't exist, as this is what is shipped with OSX and is required for some system/OS stuff to run. The reason you have so many `site-packages` directories (you actually have more than you listed in your question) is that it seems like you've installed a python.org version (the `/Library/Frameworks/...` one) and perhaps a third-party version from Homebrew or some other package manager (MacPorts by default installs into the `/opt/local` directory). Your version of `pip` was also installed from that source, so if you want to use the python.org version as your default then you'll need to [install `pip` again](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) (make sure you use [the `setuptools` version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), as `distribute` is defunct). After that's all done, you can then run `pip install numpy --upgrade` to make sure you've got the latest version, which is 1.7.1 currently.

Comment: I am looking for a clean solution. Is there a way to restore `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: @user1738154 do you still have `/usr/bin/pythonw`? It is identical to the `python` binary, so a `sudo cp /usr/bin/pythonw /usr/bin/python` should do the trick.

Comment: That is strange. After doing what you said I get `cp: /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/pythonw are identical (not copied)`

Comment: @user1738154 so apparently you have `/usr/bin/python` after all... so much for that problem :)

Comment: Well there is a Unix Executable File called python.

Comment: What happens when you set your $path to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/opengeo/pgsql/9.1/bin` ?